# Flutter TextFormField create a persistent text part inside the TextFromField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

See the image for a clear explanation of what I would like to achieve.

[image: The image]

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far? Are you referring to different text style?

Comment: fix the text you want to persist as like image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it working working.

```
child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 14, 14, 14),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/workspaceIcon.png')),
                      ),
                      // icon is 48px widget.
                    ),
                    FittedTextFieldContainer(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: workspaceController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "your-workspace",
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: lightPurple,
                          fontSize:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontSize,
                          fontWeight:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontWeight,
                          fontFamily:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontFamily,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      ".tickvent.com",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: lightPurple,
                        fontSize:
                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontSize,
                        fontWeight:
                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontWeight,
                        fontFamily:
                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2?.fontFamily,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should say that there are many ways to achieve this.
For example,

it covers everything and contains three fields lined up side by side.

Container -> Row -> Icon, TextField or TextFormField and Text.

There will most likely be overflow issues. You can wrap items in the row as expanded.

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // color: const Color(0xFFF1F0FA),
          // border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF6C5CE7), width: 1)
          ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.business_center)),
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
                // ...
                ),
          ),
          Expanded(child: Text(".tickvent.com"))
        ],
      ),
    )
```